# For loop in Timber Twig file returns three copies of same image (should be 3 different images)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm building my first Timber Wordpress theme and using the timber-starter-theme. I have a custom content type with custom fields (fields added using WCK plugin). I haven't touched single.php file, just building the twig template.  'team_church_slide' is a repeating field to add images to go into a Slick carousel. My template section is:

```
{% set slickSlider = post.team_church_slideshow %}  {# the field group #}
{% set slickSlide = post.get_image('team_church_slide') %} {# the field #}
  {% if slickSlider %}
    <div class="slick-slider">
      <ul>
      {% for slides in slickSlider %}
        <li><img src="{{ slickSlide.src }}" alt="{{ slickSlide.alt }}"></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

This returns the image correctly, but three copies of the first image, not the three different images which are uploaded. If I remove an uploaded image, two copies of the first image are shown.

Is there something to change in the twig to get all the images?

Comment: You are using the wrong variable inside your for-loop, should be `slides.src`

Comment: Hi @DarkBee - just tried that but it gives me an empty `<img src"">` (x 3)

Comment: It looks like `slickSlide` holds a single image. How should this work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out thanks to something in this post:
[Get first row from ACF Repeater using Timber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921765/get-first-row-from-acf-repeater-using-timber)

Here's my final working template section:

```
{% set slickSlider = post.team_church_slideshow %}
{% if slickSlider %}
<div class="slick-slider">
  <ul>
    {% for slides in slickSlider %}
    {% set slickSlide = TimberImage(slides.team_church_slide) %}
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="{{ slickSlide.src }}" alt="{{ slickSlide.alt }}">
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The only real change was 'post.get_image' to 'TimberImage' & moving the set inside the for-loop.

Comment: It works but if anyone can explain why post.get_image counted the number of entries but then returned the first image x times, while TimberImage gets the correct different images I'd be grateful!